# insert dynamic number of students into a table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table called students, which can have up to 4 students in it.
Fields are called Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how many students are going to be inserted - it all depends on how many are in the Array called "students"

This is my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO [Group] (Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4, projectdifficulty) 
VALUES(" & Convert.ToInt32(students(0)) & ", " & Convert.ToInt32(students(1)) & "," 
& Convert.ToInt32(students(2)) & ", " & Convert.ToInt32(students(3)) & ", 'complex')"
```

Sometimes, there is no students(3), so it throws an error when it goes to insert it.
How can i get around this?
Will I have to use an if statement with VB?

Thanks.

Comment: wrong table structure

Comment: Any errors that you have should be posted as part of your question.

Comment: The error I am getting is "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

This is because I'm trying to insert students(3) when it doesn't exist...

If it doesn't exist, i just want it to insert a null integer.

Comment: Is it just students(3) that doesn't exist or could it be students(2), students(1) etc. In short will you have less than 3 three students

Comment: There can be anywhere from 1-4 students...
If there is one, Student1 needs to be populated from students(0), and the rest need to be null...

Comment: just use an `If` `Then` `ElseIf` statement using the [`UBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f(v=vs.90).aspx) function, start by checking if `Ubound(students) = 3` if so create your insert statement then do the same for each possibility.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use parameters to do this to avoid datatype and injection issues. Second, use an iif statement. Here is just one of the many ways you could handle this. *This assumes you want a zero for empty array values. You will need to change to meet your needs*

```
Using CN As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your connection String")
    Using CMD As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Group] (Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4, projectdifficulty) " & _
            "VALUES(@P1, @P2,@P3,@P4, 'complex')", CN)

        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", IIf(students.length > 0, Convert.ToInt32(students(0)), 0))
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", IIf(students.length > 1, Convert.ToInt32(students(1)), 0))
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", IIf(students.length > 2, Convert.ToInt32(students(2)), 0))
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P4", IIf(students.length > 3, Convert.ToInt32(students(3)), 0))

        CN.Open()
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CN.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```